# Manual command not known 'dkpg --configure -a'

Tags: dpkg

64 packages updates were interrupted and I have tried typing 'dpkg-- configure -a' in terminal to no avail. 
Is this the correct command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With commands to a computer, you need to be very exact, more so than what you may be used to in everyday live. In everyday live, the recipient of your messages may correct small mistakes, because they can guess what you've probably meant.

When you're "talking" to a computer, there's no such guessing, or only to a very small degree. If you get a typo into your command, put a space in the wrong place, use the wrong number of hyphens or anything like that, the computer doesn't understand you and your command won't work.

In your case, at least in the question you wrote

```
dpkg-- configure -a
```

You probably meant to say

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

Also, in the question title you've mixed up `dpkg` and `dkpg`. As I said, small mistakes like that can break things if you're "talking" to a computer.

Additionally, you might want to look into what privileges the user account you're using on your machine has. `dpkg` is a command that requires more privileges than the "usual" user account has, because you can break things quite badly with it. Maybe you need to use `sudo` with it.

In general, I'd suggest that you read up on a few basics. As I said, it's easy to break things on a computer with a single typo or a small oversight. But don't be disheartened, everybody started out as a beginner once ;)

Comment: Thank you for that. I will not be disheartened.

Comment: Ive done it. Thank you I copied and pasted your command..